# Concept of "active" resource in a REST API

Tags: http, rest, design-patterns

I'm working on a REST API in which a particular resource can be designated as "active." To illustrate, here's a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve:

Suppose I have a URI that represents a collection of books: `/books`.

A given book has a canonical URI of the form `/books/{id}`.

I have another URI which provides a pointer to the active book: `/books/active`. This will simply send an HTTP 303 referencing the canonical URI for the active book.

What is the best way to allow a client to also update the active book? Should I allow a client to issue a PUT on `/books/active` specifying the canonical URI for the active book, or is there another generally-accepted pattern for doing this sort of thing? (It seems strange to me that a client would issue a PUT that sends the canonical URI rather than an actual representation of the resource.)

**Update:** Only one book can be active at a time (mutually exclusive), so I don't think it makes sense to make the active flag a property of the book itself, since that would imply that more than one book could have the value set to true.

Comment: Is active a property of the book resource?  Also, is there a higher level resource that contains the books (like shelf etc...)?

Comment: @bryanmac I've updated my question to clarify the definition of active. And, yes, there is a higher-level resource in my case. I was just trying to keep the example simple, but feel free to use a higher-level resource as part of an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Only one book can be active at a time in the entire system? Or is this per user?

Comment: I also don't understand why issuing a PUT using the canonical URI would seem strange to you. Using the URI as resource ID is built into the very definition of GET and PUT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad idea to build state into your URIs by allowing something like `PUT /books/active`. It completely screws with the server's ability to provide adequate caching and has been [called out as an anti-pattern](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Caching-Hypermedia-API) by Tim Stokes.

URIs in a RESTful system should uniquely identify a resource. While the representation of the resource may change (and the state of the resource may change), the same URI should never be used to point to a different resource. Doing so goes against the expected semantics of methods such as GET and PUT.

In your case, what's wrong with simply including a query parameter on the books collection? Something like, `GET /books?state=active`, for instance. That would return you the collection of all active books (which may always be 1 book, but what if that changes in the future?) You could drill down from there and `PUT` to the canonical URI.

Even better, build up a link relation architecture and simply include a relation for "active-book" next to the "self" link for the books collection. That way your client doesn't even need to be aware of your URL convention; it can simply follow the link the server provides.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the excellent video. I like the advice you give in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a higher level resource that contains the books, then it can have a property which is activeBook with a value of the book id and/or full url to the active book.  For example, if a user had a bookshelf then /user/myShelf would have books and the active book I was reading would be the active one from that my shelf.

This is more elegant than having a property on each and every book like isActive or putting state in the url.

We had a similar issue in one of our public APIs and went this route.  It's hard to say for sure without clear insight into all the resources and their relationships.  Maybe if you clarify the relationships a bit more ...

Comment: I don't know what happened. I didn't mean to downvote this answer, and now my vote is locked. Could you re-edit your response so that I can remove the downvote?